# How to prevent Angular Material 6 DatePicker with Momentjs to convert incorect format?

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, angular-material, momentjs

I am using Angular Material Datepicker with Momentjs that is helping me use any type of dividers for days, month and year (like /, . etc.).

It works perfectly when selecting a date, and adding a correct or almost correct format, that is: DD/MM/YYYY.

I have included in my module:

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};
```

and then:

```
  providers: [
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
```

The problem is happening when a user is typing a date in the format YYYY/MM/DD it gets automatically converted in DD/MM/YYYY, and that shouldn't happen, as it will be incorrect.

How can I prevent this from happening, how can I stop Momentjs from converting this format and keep the input as invalid?

Answer (score 1):

There is no configuration in the Angular Material Datepicker change that behavior. But you can achieve the same by adding a hidden input field and bonding with the datepicker. 
Here is an example how I did it.

In the **HTML** file:

```
<mat-form-field>
<input matInput #autocomplete placeholder="Please choose a date">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

In the **ts** file:

```
toFormattedDate(iso: string) {
  const date = new Date(iso);
  console.log(date);
  return `${date.getDate()}/${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getFullYear()}`;
}
```

Look at my [**Stackblitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1lpzty-fah5mv?file=app%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts).